# Implicit solutions to differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definition

Ordinary differential equations are often of the form $f^{'}(x)=F(f(x),x)$. Solutions to such equations are functions that satisfy them and are differentiable.

If we integrate both sides of the equation we get $f(x)=f(0)+\int_{0}^{x}F(f(t),t)dt$, which looks like a solution but on the other hand we can also view it as an equivalent equation.

Which of those two things is it, is it both?

Comment: The latter one. It is not strictly speaking equivalent though. The following holds: any solution to the original ode solve the integral equation and any continuous solution to the integral equation solves ode.

Comment: @Artem is it convention not to consider impicit solutions as bonafide solutions?

Comment: This is not a solution, please check what it means to solve a differential equation.

Comment: @Artem a solution is a function that satisfy the equation on some intervall. The above $f$ is a function and it does satisfy the equation. It donst say it cant depend on $f$, not in  my text nor on wikipedia.

Comment: Because it is assumed that you know what function is.

Comment: @Artem damn, a function needs to have values, therefore it cannot be implicit since then we do not have any values! Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything called solution has to add some information. The transformation into the somewhat equivalent integral form is valid for all explicit order-1 ODE, as you carried out, thus no information gain.

Usually one understands under implicit solution the transformation into some implicit equation $0=G(x,f(x),C)$. This, while still no direct computation procedure for the value $f(x)$ from $x$ alone however provides more information as it allows to numerically compute or at least refine (from one Euler step from the last value for instance) the value $f(x)$ without reference to the whole history up to the initial point.

Comment: you are saying that $f(x)=f(0)+\int_{0}^{x}F(f(t),t)dt$ is not an implicit solution but just the equation? but f(x)=G(f(x),x) is implicit since it only depends only  "pointwise" on $x$

Comment: Is there a definte way to seperate implict solutions and equtions then btw?

Comment: An implicit solution is an implicit equation that allows to compute the solution. In the integral equation you need the values of $f$ on $[0,x]$ to determine the value at $x$. In the task "*solve $F(x,y,C)=0$ for $y$*" you only need some general idea of the correct region to select among the isolated solutions the one belonging to the solution. The jump in the quality of the inputs, a continuous amount vs. a discrete amount, should be obvious. Thus this very large step towards an explicit solution deserves the name "implicit solution".

Comment: And we consider the continous amout not to be computable?(and thus it is still an equation). While an equation which gives us the possbility to acutally obtain an actual value(possible for finite number of discrete data) is considered implicit(an implicit solution). Lastly we have the case where we have $y=y(t)$ where we for one value of $t$ get an real number.(an explicit solution). Is that how your comment should be understood?

Comment: With "continuous" I mean uncountably infinite, as in "the amount of points in an interval of real numbers". "Implicit" is in negation of "explicit". And "explicit" is what you wrote, a procedure with a finite number of computational steps to reach the exact result.

Comment: ok, so an implicit solution puts us in position to obtain an explicit one? using say the implicit funtion theorem. But does not have the function defined in term of one variable "yet".

Comment: Yes. Even with the most simple class of ODE, the separable ones, you may get as best attempt at the solution something like the implicit equation $\ln(1+y)+2\arctan(y)=x+C$. The best you can now do is find the region of local solvability.

Answer (score 0):

Both equations possibly define a function, but in an implicit way. A solution needs to be explicit.

$f'(x)=f(x)$ is an equation, $f(x)=e^x$ is a solution.

Comment: Because otherwise it is not a function, since it donst have any values?

Comment: @user7534: no. They are functional equations (of the differential and integral type respectively), that do have solutions.

Comment: sorry, I was refering to the solution. An "implicit solution" is not a "solution" since it is not a function. And it is not a function since it dosnt have any values assign to it.

Comment: @user7534: no, the unknown is a function.

Comment: we must be talking past eachother, lets see if I cant make myself clearer. You said that a solution must be explicit otherwise it is not a solution. And to answer why this is the case I said that an implicitly defined solution(which is till and equation) is not a solution since the solution has to be a function.

Comment: in other words $f(x)=f(0)+\int_{0}^{x}F(f(t),t)dt$ is not a function and therefore not a solution.

Comment: @user7534: you really didn't understand my answer nor my example. They key word is *explicit*.

Comment: yes exactly, and I am tying explain why this it has to be expilicit to be a solution, just to confirm that I understood it. And I think an actual solution, to an equation has to be explicit since if it is implicitly expressed it does not constitute a function and hence not a solution.

Comment: as far as I understand and implicitly defined solution is still and equation.

Comment: @user7534: it DOES constitute a function ! That's written in the first sentence.

Comment: I tought a function needed to have values, and I dont think we can determine the values of such an expression. But I might be barking up the worng tree.

Comment: @user7534: yes, you are.

Comment: sorry, if you can think of anything else to add please do. I will let this rest for a while and try to rethink it in a bit

Comment: maybe I can ask you this, Why does a solution need to be explicit? and what distinguishes the two? and to be clear $f(x)=f(0)+\int_{0}^{x}F(f(t),t)dt$ is an implicit solution to me. Maybe I am wrong not distinguishing implicit solutions and equations.

Comment: @user7534 Solving an equation is turning it in an explicit form. Otherwise you have done nothing, the unknown is still unknown.

Comment: right, since $f(x)=f(0)+\int_{0}^{x}F(f(t),t)dt$ is not an explicit function of $x$ giving us values in $\mathbb{R}$ for each $x$ without knowing more about $f$? i.e not a function.

Comment: @user7534: you have been answered no several times. You should question your mindset and stop circling in rounds.